# Getting the html of url through bash?

Tags: linux

i'm trying to do any command that could let me type in a url, and then echo the html out in my terminal.

I found a few articles and questions showing what to do, but none seems to work.

I tried the following:

```
 $ page="$(curl http://www.cyberciti.biz/)"
 $ echo "$page"
```

but nothing happens, this prints nothing.

I've tried a bunch of other approaches, but can get nothing to work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://www.cyberciti.biz` is serving an HTTP 302 redirect with no body.

Use the `curl` `-L` option to follow these redirects.

Comment: oh yeah, did a typo when typing in here. will edit. It still does nothing

Comment: Maybe redirection to HTTPS did not work? Than try: ```page="$(curl https://www.cyberciti.biz/)"``` Or try it with wget: ```page="$(wget -q -O-www.cyberciti.biz/)"```